# Can you create a dropdown in Google sheets using a vlookup?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that looks similar to this:

[image]

Is it possible to create a formula in column B that will create a dropdown with the options from columns D through F and reference the selection in column A to find the values? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understood.

Use a helper column and add the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(query(C1:F3,"SELECT D,E,F WHERE C = '"&A1&"'")),"")
```

Then at B1, select "List from a range" in data validation dialog and enter the following in criteria:

```
=$I$2:$I$14
```

Link to example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qAd7WFUjkMBTgxheoLRjG_RHXBplwg_qMSmXAbOsC1s/edit?usp=sharing

-Prior answer-
I would use a helper column.

```
B1: =TRANSPOSE({C3:F3,C4:F4,C5:F5})
```

Then simply reference B1:B.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, and sorry if I wasn't clear enough - but the value in B1 should be referencing what is selected from the drop down in column A. So for example of I select Dog from the drop down in column A, column B would populate a dropdown with the options - Ground, Fur and Grass.

Comment: Updated answer.