# Using the fill handle, but skipping cells

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to use the fill handle but have the pattern skip cells? Every time I try to start with a sheet like this:

[image]

When I use the fill handle sheets does this:

[image]

I've read that you need to select the entire pattern (for example, cells A1 through A9 in the example above), but that doesn't seem to make a difference for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to autofill one row with the numbers and spaces using the fill handle (selecting the first three cells) and use the concatenate function on the others to fill the cell values. After this was done, it was just a matter of copy/paste!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You only need the `1` in A1. Nothing below it. Select A1:A3 (i.e., the `1` and two null cells) and then pull the fill handle down.

Comment: Follow up question - can the same be done with cell references so that it only increments by one every third cell? I have an example spreadsheet here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vnvvU9Cz-mjQf0foFg4nXI_w5K7V9eo5uxNJTzNhRXI

Comment: It may be more beneficial to explain more fully the big picture of what you're trying to do and why than to pose these isolated questions without context. The short answer is that formulas work differently from manual input. But depending on why you are trying to get formulas skipping rows, it may be able to be accomplished a different way. One important thing for me to understand would be what you plan to do with the blank cells between the formulas in that column. If you plan to enter something into them manually, you'll need to use script. If not, there are other approaches.

Comment: Sure thing. I asked a question recently here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67641287/can-you-create-a-dropdown-in-google-sheets-using-a-vlookup
Previously I only required a few cells in the helper column, but now columns D through F are much larger and the helper column needs to expand to match it.

Comment: I don't see how the other post you linked to has anything to do with what you're asking in this post. Keep in mind that we don't start out knowing what is in your head regarding your end goal. We know only what we can see here in front of us. Without referencing the other post, can you explain why you are wanting formulas in every third row? Better yet, SHOW it on a sample spreadsheet along with side-bar explanations, and share the link.

Comment: Okay. Please see this sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SVSgd9_tCOG0NOYg2LsjTzEk4uVNp2mntc42pVtoCyI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: There seems to be a significant communication issue here, I'm afraid. It seems from what you have in your sheet that you are trying to make dependent drop-down menus in Columns B and C. That can't be accomplished with your helper column. You'd wind up having to set the Data Validation for every cell in Column C separately; and then it doesn't make sense to have the helper column at all, you'd just directly reference E:G. To my knowledge, the only way to accomplish dependent drop-downs is via script.

Comment: The person who helped you with the previous post linked in your comment above assumed you would only need to make ONE selection in A1 and get ONE set of three answers in B1. But you are wanting to be able to select something in multiple rows and have a matching subset show up in a drop-down in the corresponding cell to the right. Again, that cannot be done with formulas or helper columns. It must be done with scripting.